# abstract-class in java

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

Is possible to create objects of an abstract class in Java

Comment: It is a beginner question, but a valid one.

Comment: Good form and a gold star to the SO community for no lmgtfy answers, plus a number of helpful straightforward explanations.

Answer (score 4):

If you had an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
     public void bar()
     {
         car();
     }

     protected abstract void car();
}
```

if you were able to do this:

```
final Foo foo;

foo = new Foo();
foo.bar();
```

what would happen when the "bar" method called the "car" method given that the "car" method has no code associated with it?

You can do this however:

```
class Star 
    extends Bar
{
    protected void car()  
    {
    }
}
```

and then do:

```
final Foo foo;

foo = new Star();
foo.bar();
```

This time you have a variable of type Foo that can hold any concrete subclass of Foo (a class that is not abstract is concrete).  Now when you call the "bar" method it uses the one in Foo, and when the "car" method is called it uses the one in Star.  That is an example of polymorphism.

Answer (score 3):

An attempt to instantiate an abstract class will fail at compile time unless you provide the implementation of all its abstract methods (by implementing an anonymous inner class):

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }
};
```

Comment: You might have used an example that contains an abstract class (Runnable is an interface)... :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a complete newbie question, here's what abstract classes are in Java:

There's three main types of classes in java, *interfaces*, *abstract classes* and *classes*. Each of these adds something specific to the actual class definition;

- **Interface** defines the methods one can find (*and must implement*) in a class. In short, interfaces define behaviour.
- **Abstract classes** implement some functionality and on top of that define additional *abstract methods* which must be implemented by the classes extending. Using abstract classes is similar to direct class inheritance.
- **Classes** are just, well, classes which you most likely are already familiar with.

There's plenty of reasons for using any of the possible class types, however most commonly in modern Java code you will see a lot of interfaces and a bunch of classes implementing those interfaces.

**Examples: Class**

Consider the following class:

```
public class Cat {
 public void speak() {
  System.out.println("Meow!");
 }
 public void eat(Food f) {
  System.out.println("Om nom nom, this "+f.getName()+" is delicious!"); 
 }
}
```

This is a very simple class and the kind every Java coder, even the beginners, are familiar with. Nothing special here. However with this you have an issue: what if you have a `Dog` that's basically the same but it obviously barks instead of meows?

**Example: Abstract class**

The "`Cat` or `Dog`" problem can be solved with inheritance. Traditionally standard inheritance looks like this:

```
public class Animal {
 public void eat(Food f) {
  System.out.println("Om nom nom, this "+f.getName()+" is delicious!");
 }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
 public void speak() {
  System.out.println("Meow!");
 }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
 public void speak() {
  System.out.println("Bark! Bark!");
 }
}
```

However herein lies a problem: To actually make the `Cat` meow or the `Dog` bark, you have to have code which checks what kind of animal exactly the animal is, cast it to correct type and then call the method:

```
if (animal instanceof Dog) {
 ((Dog) animal).speak();
} else if (animal instanceof Cat) {
 ((Cat) animal).speak();
}
```

As you can see, this sort of code is completely pointless! Surely we would like to just be able to call `animal.speak()` directly, right? And for that purpose, we have abstract classes! By replacing the `Animal` class in the example above with this

```
public abstract class Animal {
 public void eat(Food f) {
  System.out.println("Om nom nom, this "+f.getName()+" is delicious!");
 }
 public abstract void speak();
}
```

you can make your `Dog` bark and `Cat` meow just by calling `animal.speak()`! Great, isn't it?

Note that you could also define the default behaviour of `speak()` to `Animal` and then just override that method in `Cat` and `Dog` and sometimes that even does make sense more than what I just showed here.

Anyway, another problem arises: What if your `Dog` is an `Animal` and also a `Pet`? Java only allows for single inheritance to avoid [diamond inheritance problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) so you can't just have another superclass for them. You could add it as a superclass for `Animal` but then again, not all animals are pets - there certainly isn't a hippo in my yard pond!

**Example: Interface**

Since interfaces only *define* behaviour instead of actually *implement* them (*and that's actually the related keyword!*) you can use interfaces to define additional behaviour to your original class. Lets assume that pets generally can be groomed among other things, so the interface for `Pet` would be like this:

```
public interface Pet {
 void groom(Brush b);
}
```

Now just add `implements Pet` to your `Dog` and it's now groomable! Just to make sure, the first line of your `Dog` class should look like this:

```
public class Dog extends Animal implements Pet {
```

Now to groom your `Dog` or any other `Pet` you can do this:

```
if (animal instanceof Pet) ((Pet) animal).groom();
```

That's  pretty much it. As an exercise, try implementing `Animal` as an interface; do note that interfaces can actually extend other interfaces.

PS. Also enums and anonymous inner classes can be considered as class types, however they're not quite the main ones everyone should know right after learning the basics of Java.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean.

If you mean: "can I have an instance of an abstract class" -- sure; any instance of a concrete subclass (of an abstract class) implicitly *is* an instance of the abstract super type too.

If you mean: "can I have an instance of an abstract class without defining a concrete subtype" -- yes, if some library (for example javassist, cglib) generates a concrete subtype for you.

If you mean "will the following expression ever pass":

```
assert Modifier.isAbstract(x.getClass().getModifiers());
```

the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate an abstract class (calling `new` on it), if that is what you mean.

It is possible to have instances of subclasses. Those objects are also `instanceof` the abstract class, meaning that you can cast them to it.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on it. its clean and decent [javacanal.blogspot.com/](http://javacanal.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 0):

No. Its not possible. You need to create a class which extends the abstract class, and then you can create an object of the subclass.

**Please find the example:**

```
abstract class AbstractClass{

    public abstract String abstractMethod(String param1,String param2);

    public void nonAbstractMethod(String param){
        System.out.println("Value of param is "+param);
    }
}

class NonAbstractClass extends AbstractClass{
    public String abstractMethod(String param1,String param2){
        String param = param1 + param2;
        return param;
    }
}


public class DemoClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NonAbstractClass nonAbstractClass = new NonAbstractClass();
        nonAbstractClass.abstractMethod("param1", "param2");
        nonAbstractClass.nonAbstractMethod("param1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes and no... the class that extends the abstract class must itself not be abstract for this to be true.